# Are examples of double-embedded content clause subjects attested?

Tags: syntax, clauses, embedding

Have you ever come across an example of a dually embedded content clause functioning as subject, such as

*That that it works is obvious is disputed.*

Comment: "That its working is obvious is disputed."  "Its workings being obvious is disputed."  "For its workings being obvious to be disputed is surprising."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this type of embedding is discussed (and marked with #: semantically or pragmatically anomalous) in Huddleston & Pullum's CGEL in the section called 'Processing factors', pp 1405-6. Also, Pullum tells me that such examples are never found. "Fred Householder asserted in a couple of book reviews in *Language* that English has a surface constraint forbidding "that that". Terry Langendoen's view is that it's a processing matter: stashing two subordinators in a row as promissory notes for finite clauses that are to come is too much of a strain on the old processing box."

Comment: A surface constraint forbidding "that that" seems an overreach to me. I find sentences such as "I think that that she's innocent is beyond dispute"  grammatical in speech, where the second *that* would have to start a new intonational phrase. But as H&P say, it's not possible for subjects.